# Distinct not working as expected with sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, distinct

How does distinct work with the following table:

```
id  | id2    | time
-------------------
1   | 5555 | 12
2   | 5555 | 12
3   | 5555 | 33
4   | 9999 | 44
5   | 9999 | 44
6   | 5555 | 33

select distinct * from table
```

Comment: How does it work when you execute that query?

Comment: that was my doubt actually

Comment: i don't understand why down voting this question, i believe this question is meaningful.Thanks

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name i have updated my question, will make sure not repeating this kind of mistakes.Thank you

Comment: What do you *expect* this to do?  I'm sure `distinct` is working, you just need to understand it better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use `select distinct * from table` all the row are distinct

if you use

```
 select distinct id2  , time from table
```

then you obtain

```
    id2 | time

   5555 | 12
   5555 | 33
   9999 | 44
```

With distinct you obtain the distinct rows based on the result of the select

Comment: i can accept only after 5 mins, i have already tried accepting this answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Each row here is different, so `distinct` will have no visible effect, and all the rows will be returned.

Comment: let me guess, if the distinct gonna work, all rows must be have the same repeat values?How about  4 rows with first two rows are same and last two rows are same ?Will it return two rows?

Comment: @youv yup, that will return two rows.

Answer (score 1):

```
Select Distinct ID2 From SomeTable
```

Will return
5555
9999